# "Storage space running low. Some system functions may not work"

Tags: insufficient-memory, sony-xperia-v

I have  Sony Xperia v3 and I always get the error "Storage space is running low. Some system functions may not work." What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: "*what should I do to solve this problem*" -- I suggest taking a look at the tag-wiki [insufficient-memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). It has lots of similar answered questions that would help you to resolve or lead you to next step in solving the issue. Do come back to this question if you don't find anything useful or for posting an answer to help someone in future. :)

Comment: Tanks u very much

Answer (score 1):

This question is way too broad and was asked to death, general consensus is

1. remove applications and media you don't need, if you are rooted remove unused system apps
2. move as much applications to sd-card
3. install a cleaning application (like clean master), they can make a difference
4. use cloud applications such as dropbox to sync your heavy files across multiple computers and devices, why store all those >5MB pictures you've taken on your limited device if your Hard drive has much more capacity?